# "undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()" qtcreator with cmake

Tags: qt, boost, cmake

I try to use boost in **qtcreator(windows)** with **Cmake**, Cmake can find boost "**system**" and "**thread**" sucessfully, but there is there is a problem "undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()" while compiling. I searched problem like this, adding "**-lboost_system**" maybe a solution,but there is no **".pro"** file in my project,so how to add it in CMakeLists.
Below is part of my CmakeLists:

```
project(demo)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.9)

set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
set(DEBUG_FLAG _d)

set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
find_package(Qt5Gui REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt5Core REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt5Widgets REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt5Xml REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt5Quick REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt5Qml REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt5Declarative)

find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)
find_package(Boost 1.58 REQUIRED COMPONENTS system thread)
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})
link_directories(${Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS})

set(OGRE_RESOURCE_FOLDER ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/resources)
set(OGRE_HOME "D:/3rd/OGRE")
set(OGRE_PLUGIN_FOLDER "${OGRE_HOME}\\bin")
include_directories(
"${OGRE_HOME}\\include"
"${OGRE_HOME}\\include\\OGRE"
"${OGRE_HOME}\\include\\OGRE\\RenderSystems\\GL"
"${OGRE_HOME}\\boost")
link_directories(${LINK_DIRECORIES} "${OGRE_HOME}\\lib"       "${OGRE_HOME}\\lib\\opt")


include_directories("C:/3rd/Eigen" "C:/3rd/robotics/include" "D:/3rd/Eigen"     "D:/3rd/robotics/include")
link_directories("C:/3rd/robotics/lib" "D:/3rd/robotics/lib")
add_library(robot src/robot.cpp)

add_library(QOgre src/QOgreWidget.cpp)
qt5_use_modules(QOgre OpenGL Widgets Xml)


add_executable(OGREDemo src/QOgreWidgetDemo.cpp src/ogredemo.cpp )
qt5_use_modules(OGREDemo OpenGL Widgets Xml)
target_link_libraries(OGREDemo ${OPENGL_LIBRARIES} ${BOOST_LINK_LIBS_DEBUG}
OgreMain${DEBUG_FLAG} OIS${DEBUG_FLAG}
orocos-kdl${DEBUG_FLAG} robot QOgre )

file(GLOB_RECURSE QMLS "." "*.qml")
qt5_add_resources(RESOURCES_ADDED resources/qml.qrc)
set_source_files_properties(${RESOURCE_ADDED} PROPERTIES GENERATED ON)
add_executable(recat src/main.cpp src/QmlOgre.cpp ${RESOURCES_ADDED}        ${QMLS})
qt5_use_modules(recat Widgets Xml Quick Qml Core Gui Declarative)
target_link_libraries(recat ${OPENGL_LIBRARIES} ${BOOST_LINK_LIBS_DEBUG}
OgreMain${DEBUG_FLAG} OIS${DEBUG_FLAG} RenderSystem_GL${DEBUG_FLAG}
orocos-kdl${DEBUG_FLAG} robot)

configure_file (
"${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/plugins.cfg.in"
"${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/plugins.cfg"
)

configure_file (
"${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/resources.cfg.in"
"${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/resources.cfg"
)
```

And detailed problem description：

```
D:\3rd\robotics_android\src\QOgreWidgetDemo.cpp:-1: error: undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'

error: CMakeFiles\OGREDemo.dir/objects.a(QOgreWidgetDemo.cpp.obj): bad reloc address 0x1b in section `.text$_ZNK5boost6system10error_code7messageEv[__ZNK5boost6system10error_code7messageEv]'
```

Comment: Have you added the right flags to your target?

Comment: You have to link your executable against boost_system, I assume

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld I link boost libs like this :  target_link_libraries(OGREDemo ${OPENGL_LIBRARIES} ${BOOST_LINK_LIBS_DEBUG} OgreMain${DEBUG_FLAG} OIS${DEBUG_FLAG} orocos-kdl${DEBUG_FLAG} robot QOgre )，is that any problem？

Comment: @usr1234567 I added the whole content of my CMakeLists.txt above，is any  flags i forget to set？

Comment: Try target_link_libraries(OGREDemo ... ${Boost_SYSTEM_LIBRARY_DEBUG})

Comment: Just as David said. And never add link directories directly, always detect the library and pass these variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right variable to link against is *Boost_SYSTEM_LIBRARY_DEBUG*. As @usr1234567 stated it is not necessary to use *link_directories*.

For reference see: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/FindBoost.html